# How to make partitions with in /home/user/ writable by user?

Tags: files, permissions, mount, directory

I have a partition scheme like this:

```
/
/home/
/home/user/files/
```

When logged in as `user`, I cannot save any files at `/home/user/files/`. The only solution I can find is to create a new subdirectory as root, e.g. `/home/user/files/files/`, then as root, change the ownership to `user`. That would allow me to put files into `/home/user/files/files/`.

How can I create partitions within `/home/user/`, but which are still usable, as if they were simply folders, by the ordinary `user` account?

Preferably, the user account should not have the ability to accidentally delete this partition.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried a chown, once the partition is mounted ?

```
 chown user /home/user/files/
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the partition mounted at `/home/user/files` is a Unix/Linux filesystem, such as `ext4` or `xfs`, then simply:

```
sudo chown user. /home/user/files
chmod ug+rw /home/user/files
```